# Not able to get access token from refresh token

Tags: office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

[image]

i am getting this error while requesting for a new token from a refresh token in  graph API.
can any i suggest please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are forgetting to pass the `grant_type`, which tells the token service what it should be doing.

You should pass: `grant_type=refresh_token`

This information can be found in our documentation: [Refreshing the access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#refresh-the-access-token)

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&refresh_token=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=refresh_token
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh      // NOTE: Only required for web apps
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i was being stupid and adding the grant type in header section but it has to be in body part.